# Converting special character to degree symbol

Tags: mysql

In my mysql database, i need to convert the special character � into degree symbol. I tried the following command in sql but am getting an error message.

update NOTE set NOTE_VALUE = replace(NOTE_VALUE, '�', '°');

Error msg:

```
Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT), (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'replace'.
```

I need to convert the special character � into the degree symbol.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what is your column's type/charset?

Comment: I just changed the column collation to utf8_general_ci. It was latin swedish before

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the correct value but you should be able to refer to it by its integer value `char(146)`

```
update NOTE set NOTE_VALUE = replace(NOTE_VALUE, char(XXX), '°');
```

Where XXX is a value you'll need to figure out

This article might be [helpful](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/14/bad-character-data-in-mysql/).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i tried char(186) but it does not seem to work. 186 is the code for degree character

Answer (score 0):

As seen [there](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?26,6528,225042#msg-225042) you can try to change the collation of the table (if it's not a problem)

```
ALTER table note convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_swedish_ci;
```

You can also try the `char()` method as mentioned above but with the `USING` clause ([link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char))

```
UPDATE NOTE set NOTE_VALUE = replace(NOTE_VALUE, char(XXX USING latin1_swedish_ci), '°');
```